# Control weight/boldness of axis values in Plotly javascript

Tags: javascript, css, plotly

Using the library plotly in javascript, I am trying to control the boldness of the axis value's font.

I know in the layout we can set:

```
layout= {
    ...
    xaxis: {
        tickfont: {
           family: 'MyFont'
           size: 12,
           color: '#000000'
      }
    }
}
```

How can I do ? Is there a dedicated field in the JSON layout or should I define a custom variable in a CSS file ? And in the latest case how can I do this ?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to make the axis title bold, you can use the `<b></b>` tags. Even though these are technically deprecated tags, Plotly recognizes them (and some other limited HTML tags) for axis titles.

Also, since Plotly renders plots as SVG, you can add CSS rules to the classes corresponding to the SVG elements you wish to style. So if you wanted to make the numbers on a the x-axis bold, you could add a rule like:

```
.xtick {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's an example with both x-axis title and x-axis numbers made bold using the above techniques:

```js
let trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

let data = [trace1];

let layout = {
  xaxis: {
    title: {
      text: '<b>Bold X-Axis</b>',
      font: {
        family: 'Arial, serif',
        size: 18,
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data, layout);
```

```css
.xtick {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This perfectly answers my question. However your answer brings another one: how do you find css class reference. For instance you refer to xtick, but how do you know the reference? For instance if I want to change hoverlabel which one should I use? Where can I find references ?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can right click on the element and click "Inspect". That will open the developer tools and you can see the classes and other attributes of the element you clicked on.

Comment: Ah yes ofc why I didn't think about it ! Thank you very much :)